# How to typescript `this` when it is dynamic?

Tags: typescript

I'm converting a series of JavaScript projects to typescript, and a common paradigm that I've used has been the following:

```
abstract class A {
    static create (…args) {
        return new this(…args)
    }
    /* a bunch of things */
}

class B extends A {
    a: number
    b: string
    constructor(a: number, b: string) {
        super()
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }
    /* a bunch of things */
}

class C extends A {
    /* a bunch of things */
}
```

Which offers the compelling syntactic sugar of `require('module').B.create()`.

I cannot figure out how to make this valid typescript.

Additional complexity, is that consumers of the package may also extend class A too, so I am not aware of all the extensions at the time of authorship.

---

With:

```
abstract class A {
    static create<T extends typeof A>(this: T, ...args: any): T {
        const Klass = this
        const instance = new Klass(...args)
        return instance
    }
}

class B extends A {
    a: number
    b: string
    constructor(a: number, b: string) {
        super()
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }
}

class C extends A { }
```

I get the error:

> [ts] Cannot create an instance of an abstract class. [2511]

---

With the following, that omits the abstract for debugging:

```
class A {
    static create<T extends typeof A>(this: T, ...args: any): T {
        const Klass = this
        const instance = new Klass(...args)
        return instance
    }
}

class B extends A {
    a: number
    b: string
    constructor(a: number, b: string) {
        super()
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }
}

class C extends A { }
```

I get an error about the variable arguments:

> [ts] Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 or more. [2556]

---

With:

```
type StaticThis<T> = { new(): T };

abstract class A {
    static create<T extends typeof A>(this: StaticThis<T>, ...args: any): T {
        const Klass = this
        const instance = new Klass(...args)
        return instance
    }
}

class B extends A {
    a: number
    b: string
    constructor(a: number, b: string) {
        super()
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }
}

class C extends A { }
```

I solve the abstract error, but keep the arguments error:

> [ts] Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 or more. [2556]

---

With:

```
interface Factory<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T
}

abstract class A {
    static create<T extends A>(this: Factory<T>, ...args: any): T {
        return new this(...args)
    }
}

class B extends A {
    a: number
    b: string
    constructor(a: number, b: string) {
        super()
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }
    foo() {

    }
}

class C extends A {
    bar() {

    }
}
```

It works as expected, however Visual Studio Code autocompletes `B.create` to `B.create(this)`, which may be a seperate bug.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) your issue?

Comment: @jcalz thank you, it seems so, want to post the typescript compatible code snippet in an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a minor modification to the [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-410887254) alluded to in the [relevant issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) will also give you the proper constructor argument checking for each subclass, at least since TypeScript 3.0 introduced [generic rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters):

```
type StaticThis<Args extends any[], T> = { new(...args: Args): T };

abstract class A {
  public static create<Args extends any[], T extends A>(
    this: StaticThis<Args, T>,
    ...args: Args
  ): T {
    const Klass = this
    const instance = new Klass(...args)
    return instance
  }
}

class B extends A {
  a: number
  b: string
  constructor(a: number, b: string) {
    super()
    this.a = a
    this.b = b
  }
}

class C extends A { }

const b = B.create(1, "b"); // okay
const c = C.create(); // okay
const badB = B.create(2, 3); // error, type '3' not assignable to type 'string';
const badC = C.create(4); // error, expected 0 arguments
const badA = A.create(); // error, can't use abstract class here
```

I'm kind of not sure about why you'd rather jump through these hoops instead of just using `new` on the subclasses, but you probably have your reasons.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

File 1 =>

```
 export namespace Shapes {
        export namespace Polygons {

            export class A {
                static create <T extends A>(): T {
                    return <T>new this();
                }

                sayHi(){
                    console.log('Hi')
                }
            }

            export class B extends A{
                sayHiFromB() {
                    console.log('Hi From B');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

File 2 =>

```
import * as myImport from './testing';


    const myInstanceA = myImport.Shapes.Polygons.A.create();
    myInstanceA.sayHi();


    const myInstanceB = myImport.Shapes.Polygons.B.create<myImport.Shapes.Polygons.B>();
    myInstanceB.sayHi();
    myInstanceB.sayHiFromB();
```

Result =>
[image: Result =>]

Comment: This drops the `abstract` and also removes the support for passing arguments to the extended classes.